# Layout over layout that can move

Tags: android, animation, layout

I am writing an Android app but cannot figure out how to have a layout over another layout that can animate up and down to show and hide its contents, but have the bottom layout's imageview, shrink to fit the new area.

An example of what I am trying to do is in this iPhone app.

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/alex-ze-pirate-comic/id526432227?mt=8

Screenshots 2 & 4 show the states that I mean. When the top layout goes down to leave just the toolbar, the imageview gets taller to use the extra space provided.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ImageView in this case will stay the same. Your second View will simply be covering it for some time. You can achieve this effect using a [sliding drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Comment: Ok, after some thought about the future of the app, I've decided to redesign the app to think more about Android. The Sliding Drawer is probably the way I am going to go with this new design.